# google map with android. having more than on application on my debug key

Tags: android, google-maps

Since Google moved to android map API v2 you have to connect your SHA1 key with a packagename. On the page it says 'packages' in plural but i can't seem to find out if and how it is possible to connect to package names to the same account

I would like to develop application with both 'com.foo...' AND 'com.bar...' 
Do i really have to use the same package names for all my applications? or create new keys for each project?

Thanks for helping me out

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the same for both. Since, the API key is already stored in your debug.keystore in the .android folder. But if you want to publish your app in the play store officially. You may have to make an another one since they didn't support the same keyvalue for two apps.

Answer (score 0):

Ben dubugginge my application and trying to make new ones...

You have to create one key for each project. giving you the ability to see statistics for each application.

But you can use the same debug keystore (created when installing the sdk?) to create as many keys as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the [Google Api Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) and click on the "Create new Android key..." button.

There you can enter several SHA1-package combinations, like this:

```
A5:5C:9F:45:BA:62:04:53:37:E4:A4:0D:CE:D5:2C:0B:99:B8:CE:10;com.example.app1
A5:5C:9F:45:BA:62:04:53:37:E4:A4:0D:CE:D5:2C:0B:99:B8:CE:10;com.example.app2
A5:5C:9F:45:BA:62:04:53:37:E4:A4:0D:CE:D5:2C:0B:99:B8:CE:10;com.example.app3
```

If you generate a key for this text you can use the same key for all three apps above.